# "Stuff" not appearing in review queues. Invisible red blobs

Tags: support, reviews, review-queues

Since I was able to observe them (circa 4 months ago), I've observed a certain erratic behaviour of review queues, the red blob refusing to disappear in spite of when one expands the queue menu - there are no corresponding red blobs to review. Acceptable odd system behaviour - from a user's point of view. (If you're prepared to accept it that is.)

Since the migration I've noticed close-votes on one question which did not provoke the red blob top right a day or maybe two-ago, I forget which question - I shrugged it off as tiredness/inattention on my part.

[This](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/145902/help-my-death-star-suffers-from-kessler-syndrome) question seems to have recieved reopen votes. It does not currently apear in my "reopen votes" queue - as of the time of this question - and has not done so for at least the last ten minutes. And two days - unless I'm losing my faculties.

Is the bread that I'm currently eating infected with the [ergot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ergot)? Is there a series of traffic jams between servers or processes that we should know about?

Edit: Just checked again 5 minutes later: it's still not there. Oh - and two days that is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works as designed.

First for your example: you can have a look at the timeline [here](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/posts/145902/timeline) to see that the review is already over. The review says "Leave Closed", which is why it's still closed. But the votes are still there. They will slowly fade away with time, but if enough people see the question and decide to manually cast a reopen vote it will get reopened. But it won't appear in the review queue in this cycle again. That means if it's reopened and then closed and then someone would vote to reopen it *again* you could theoretically see it, as long as you haven't done a reopen review on that question ever before. But for now there is no need for it to appear, because enough users with the corresponding privilege already reviewed it. Here is the review in a close up: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/59707

The timeline is not easy to find. There is no button to it. But when you click on a post and edit your browsers address bar to replace "questions" with "posts" and the post title at the end with "timeline" you can access it. For situations like these it's very handy.

Next the not-disappearing red bubble: the thing counts all active reviews *on the site* and "alarms" everyone with the corresponding privilege once review amounts cross a certain threshold. If you've already cleared it you will still be "alarmed", even though you can't review it again. Another theoretical example would be if your own posts triggered many reviews you would also be notified that there are many outstanding reviews, even though you can't review your own stuff. This can sometimes happen on smaller sites where a couple reviews in the queue already trigger the "alarms".

Comment: Your use of the word "designed" indicates that it's definition is fungible. Frankly your answer raises more questions and issues with the software than it answers. More of a "read feature for bug" answer. Unless the PTB are just going by way of the "if it ain't broke enough to fix" - or the constructionalist "tinkering with the established edifice" ad eternam method, then we're due for a massive overhaul of the review-queue system. I wonder where we land on that question.

Comment: @Agrajag Many people have complained quite often about the bubble thing and many other review-related features. You can always try to write a feature-request on [main meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) to have something changed. An example about the confusion: [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314060/352819), where a user from Worldbuilding.SE asked about the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for the ref. may do so. Will keep an eye out and do some digging in the meantime. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The appearance (or non-appearance) of the red dot is sometimes a little haphazard.  I don't fully understand the rules for it, though opening the review drop-down is supposed to banish it for a time (don't bother users if they looked recently), and there's a minimum number of pending tasks to cause it to appear.

The question you linked to *did* go through the [reopen queue](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/59707), with mixed results.  A post is supposed to only go through any particular queue once, so if a question was closed, reopened (reviewed), closed again, and gets another reopen vote, it doesn't go back to the queue.